# F differential and convex

Tags: real-analysis

May anyone help me on this problem? If f is differentiable and convex ,$\forall$  x,x+v $\in$  $\mathbb{R}^{m}$  $\iff$ $ f(x+v)  \geq f(x)+\nabla f(x) \cdot v$?

Comment: Please, share your thoughts on this problem

Answer (score 0):

Consider $tx+(1-t)y$, $t \in [0,1]$. Take a look at
$$
g(t)=f(tx+(1-t)y). 
$$
We know get that 
$$
g(t)=f(tx+(1-t)y)=g(0)+ g'(0)t+o(t)=f(y)+t\nabla f(x)(x-y)+o(t)
$$
Using convexity, we now get for $t \neq 0$ (why can we do this?):
$$
f(y)+t\nabla f(y)(x-y)+o(t) \leq tf(x)+(1-t)f(y) \\
-t f(y)+t\nabla f(y)(x-y)+o(t) \leq tf(x) \\
 f(y)+\nabla f(y)(x-y)+\frac{o(t)}{t} \leq f(x) \\
\nabla f(y)(x-y)+\frac{o(t)}{t} \leq f(x)-f(y) \\
$$
Now letting $t \to 0$ gives us the result. Try now to re-write it for $x$ and $x+v$.